# Encode a "file://" url within an "http://" url?

Tags: google-chrome, url

I use the [Speed Dial](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dgpdioedihjhncjafcpgbbjdpbbkikmi&ei=d2p8T7OgK8rc0QGiyPT1Cw&usg=AFQjCNHPDtWuJZCjzJw1CCtVX1iSzca_wQ&sig2=KY00Xp3782UFCYBGuR0Enw&cad=rja) extension from Chrome and whenever I enter in a new `file://`
bookmark it automatically converts this to `http://file//`, and this doesn't work.  I have the LocalLink extension so I can use the file URL manually but for some reason this extension just won't play nice.  So, this is annoying and since development on this extension is dead I doubt that this will get fixed anytime soon.

So as a work around, is it possible to somehow encode `file://` in an HTTP URL? Like `http://file%3A//...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not trivially. The "http:" scheme expects that HTTP will be used to contact some sort of server. It may be possible to put up a server that performs a redirect to a file: URL, but 1) someone has to put it up, and 2) someone has to pay for the (admittedly small) traffic generated. You should consider asking the addon author to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the info although I might be more productive trying out one of the other dial extensions rather than trying to get the author to fix it..

Answer (score 0):

Adding "`file%#A//`" would create an the invalid URL. It wouldn't behave in the way that you want it to.

You should either manually edit the bookmark to remove the "`http://`" or temporarily disable the extension when creating these types of bookmarks.